# Typescript how to add new item to empty array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, vuejs2, vue-component

I have component in vue 2 which is written in typescript:

```
 data: {
    userfilterresults: []
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get("/Tasks/GetTasks")
      .then(response => {
        this.userfilterresults = response.data;
      });
  },
  methods: {
    addtab() {
      // this push bellow is the reason of the error:
      this.userfilterresults.push({
        id : '-1',
        userid : '1',
        name : 'newtab'
      });
```

And I want to add new item to existed array userfilterresults but I've got error: Argument type {..} is not assignable to parameter of type never
How I can add new item to the array?

Comment: response.data is an array?

Comment: yes, response.data is the array of objects: {
        id : '-1',
        userid : '1',
        name : 'newtab'
      }

Comment: the problem is that at the begin the array userfilterresults is empty

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to declare a type for `userfilterresults`.

By default, for `let x = []`, type of `x` will be `never[]`.

You need to specify it explicitly or mark it as `any[]`. e.g.

```
let x: any[] = []
let y: CustomType[] = []
```

I'm not familiar with the typings of Vue, but that is the underlying reason.

Try

```
data: {
  userfilterresults: [] as any[]
}
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks! You help me!
In my case 
`numbers: {numberType: string, numberGame: number}[] = [];`

Answer (score 0):

> > > userfilterresults:any= [] ;
> > >
> > > addtab() {
> > >
> > > ```
> > >   var obj={
> > >      id : '-1',
> > >     userid : '1',
> > >     name : 'newtab'
> > > ```
>
> }  }
>
> > > ```
> > >   this.userfilterresults.push(obj);
> > > ```